# Identify Phrases/Words in a Sentence

Tags: c#, web-services, machine-learning, nlp

I'm looking for an API or library that can identify certain phrases/words in a sentence or short phrase?

The application of this is to find items which are not permitted.  For instance, we will have a definitive list of phrases/words that are not permitted e.g., knife, battery, oil, paint, nail polish, glass etc.

We will then have a list of short phrases that need to be checked against this list.  Ideally the API should handle pluralisation, misspellings and number substitutions e.g., 0 as o

UPDATE 15 Oct 2021:

Over the past few months, I've been experimenting with Fuse (JavaScript) and FuzzySharp.  However, I’m still struggling to find a solution that can accurately identify words/phrases.

Using FuzzySharp, some examples of false positives are:

- “used hot water bottle” – this matched “water” with a score of 90
- “waterproof trousers” – this matched “water” with a score of 90
- “oil” – this matched “toiletries” with a score of 90
- “toilet” – this matched “toiletries” with a score of 90

I understand why these have a high score, however I’m unsure of what technology I should be using improve accuracy.  At the moment we only have 298 phrases that we want to search against

Comment: maybe Azure search with its cognitive capabilities could sort you out. It lets you index large amount of text and extract key features of it.

Comment: Be sure to research all the misadventures of those trying to "clean" cursing and such out of online speech. You'll probably find quite a few to be relevant even if your use-case is slightly different.